# Making a function that creates a new variable containing an element reference every time it is called

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a function that I want to create a new **Variable** every time it is called. The reason why it needs to be a variable is because I am storing an element reference with it. Arrays cannot store element references that I am aware of. This is my (Simplified for this purpose) code:

```js
function createPara(text) {
  let x = document.createElement("p");
  x.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}

function submit() {
  createPara(document.getElementById("input").value);
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Make new paragraph">
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Submit">
```

This code works, except after I have made a new paragraph, I can't do anything to the old ones. Like changing the background color. For example,
`x.style.backgroundColor = "red";`
will only change the newest paragraph. I want to be able to individually change each of them. I think this might be achievable with a `for` loop, but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Of course arrays can store element references. Anything you can store in a variable can also be stored in an array.

Comment: Use `array.push(x)` to add it to the array.

Comment: do you have an example of a variable that could not be added to an array?

Comment: @MisterJojo No, it was a mistake on my part. My code was flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can just create an array to save all of the elements.
Like this:

```js
let array = [];
function createPara(text) {
  let x = document.createElement("p");
  x.textContent = text;
  array.push(x);
  document.body.appendChild(x);

}
function change(){
array[document.querySelector("#number").value -1].style.color = "red";
}
function submit() {
  createPara(document.getElementById("input").value);
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Make new paragraph">
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Submit">
<br>
<input type = "number" id = "number">
<button onclick = "change();">
Change the color to red
</button>
```